# SessionLocaleResolver langage changed but not see

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use spring boot 2, spring security. I create cache for User.
In my user class, I have a lang field: FR, EN...
That allow user to select langage ui they want.

Actually, user have possibility to change it's lang.

```
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserCache userCache() throws Exception {

        return new SpringCacheBasedUserCache(new ConcurrentMapCache("userCache"));

    }
}

public class I18nLocaleResolver extends SessionLocaleResolver {

    @Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null && !"anonymousUser".equals(auth.getPrincipal())) {
            CustomUserDetails user = (CustomUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();

            String lang = user.getLang();
            if (lang == null) {
                lang = LanguagesEnum.FR.getLanguage();
            }
            Locale locale = new Locale(lang);

            WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, locale);

            return locale;
        }

        Locale locale = (Locale) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
        if (locale == null) {
            locale = determineDefaultLocale(request);
        }
        WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, locale);

        return locale;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) {
        WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, locale);

    }

}
```

In UserDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public void updateLang(Integer userId, String newLanguage) {
        Optional<Users> optUserApp = repository.findById(userId);

        if (!optUserApp.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username id " + userId + " not found");
        }

        Users user = optUserApp.get();

        user.setLang(newLanguage);

        repository.save(user);

        userCache.removeUserFromCache(user.getUsername());
    }
```

Scenario

User lang is EN, so it change it for FR, we passe by updateLang method, change it's done on the db side, after debugger go to  I18nLocaleResolver. At this place it's the old value who are see (EN). It's there a way to refresh that without logout user?

Answer (score 0):

> Some cache implementations may not support eviction from the cache, in which case they should provide appropriate behavior to alter the user in either its documentation, via an exception, or through a log message.

[SpringCacheBasedUserCache](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/cache/SpringCacheBasedUserCache.html#putUserInCache-org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails-)

Please try passing the user object instead of userName. Also try    `putUserInCache(user)` this method if you want to update user in Cache